# Доступ к MySQL из Android приложения

Tags: android, php, android-asynctask, json, mysql

Учусь на примере http://devcolibri.com/1548

Код

```
public class AllProductActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/get_all_products.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditProductActivity.class);

            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка продуктов. Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

     Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {

            int success =   json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } 
       else {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
              i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

При запуске выдает ошибки

```
02-05 12:22:30.951: E/Buffer Error(277): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 12:22:30.962: E/JSON Parser(277): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-05 12:22:31.031: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductActivity.java:160)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductActivity.java:1)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-05 12:22:31.061: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 4 more
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277): Activity com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f56550 that was originally added here
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f56550 that was originally added here
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductActivity.java:148)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.example.androidandmysql.AllProductActivity.onCreate(AllProductActivity.java:89)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 12:22:32.870: E/WindowManager(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: У вас диалог утёк, уничтожайте его в методе onDestroy. И еще на 277 строке ошибка получения jsoup Объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно не понятно, можно по-подробнее? Для чайников)

Answer (score 1):

Попробую дешифровать откровения [@Deadkenny](/users/17344/deadkenny): в коде 2 ошибки:

1. Ошибка при получении JSon объекта `AllProductActivity.java:160`
2. Утечка прогресс диалога созданного в `onPreExecute` - видимо при выкидывании экспепшна.

Общее замечание по отладке. Отлаживать AsyncTask всегда очень трудно. Посему рекомендуется сначала отладить код в юайтреде (эмулятор это позволяет, но не реальный девайс) и только затем "заносить" код под AsyncTask

Касаемо бага парсинга JSon объекта посмотрите в браузере что вам выдает ваш урл: `http://127.0.0.1/get_all_products.php` - возможно какую нибудь ересь.

Comment: в пхп вроде все в порядке, как и должно быть. 
Пример:
 {"products":[{"pid":"12","name":"qwertya","price":"147.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 15:52:11","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pid":"13","name":"qwerty","price":"1234.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 16:24:27","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}

Кстати вставка в бд тоже происходит корректно. А что с этим делать, совсем не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка происходит во время парсинга ответа. Это следует из:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0
>   of

Попробуйте только один объект в ответе "распарсить".